# Java class information is lost when extend class with more generics

Tags: java, generics

This seems to be a compiler issue, or maybe this is there by design.

`ClassA` is a class with two generics. `ClassB` will extend `ClassA` by providing one solid generic type, but still expose another one.

In the following example, `E` will be passed in type that will extend `ClassA`, so when any method is called, then returned type will still be the subtype which enables to call the subtype method if needed. The motivation behinds this is to do a builder pattern, e.g.

```
ClassB b = new ClassB<String>().m1().m2().m3().m4()......
```

```
public class ClassA<E, T> {
    public final E e;
    public final T t;

    public ClassA(T t) {
        this.e = (E)this;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public E printA() {
        System.out.println("AAAAAA");
        return e;
    }
}

public class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<ClassB, T> {
    public ClassB(T t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public ClassB printB() {
        System.out.println("BBBBBB");
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB<String> classB = new ClassB<>("Hello World");
        // classB.printA().printA().printA(); // This will fail, after the second printA() return Object type instance instead of ClassB.
        System.out.println(classB.printA().printA().getClass()); // This will print "class ClassB", so the class information it still there.
        ((ClassB)classB.printA().printA()).printA(); // Casting the instance to ClassB again will make it work again.
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you call the method two times, the return instance type will be lost, so it will be an `Object` type, and cannot call any `ClassA/B` method without casting it. This is super weird.

Any idea?

Comment: `class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<ClassB<T>, T>`

Comment: *"This seems to be a compiler issue"*. It's very unlikely. You should consider the problem is on your side.

Comment: @zefick Thank you.

Comment: "genetics" Generics, right?

Comment: @AndyTurner Fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class `ClassB` is a generic one, but you are opting out of generics when not providing a type parameter.

And you are doing exactly that here

```
public class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<ClassB, T>
                                      ^^^^^^
```

and here

```
public ClassB printB()
       ^^^^^^
```

So simply change these lines to

```
public class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<ClassB<T>, T>
                                            ^^^
```

and

```
public ClassB<T> printB()
             ^^^
```

Then it will work.